# Try statement not catching the exception inside a case block

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

```
          Dim Fields() As String = msg.Split()
          ...
          Try
            If Fields(0) = "FOO" Then
                Select Case Fields(1)
                    Case "1"
                       ...
                    Case "2"
                        ...
                    Case "3"
                       Dim some_object as A = other_object ' other_object is type B
                    Case "4"
                       ...
                    Case "5"
                       ...
                    Case "6"
                        ...
                    Case "7"
                        ...
                    Case Else
                        'TBD
                End Select
            End If

        Catch e As Exception
            Dim xyz As Integer= 0
        End Try
```

For some strange reason my Catch block is not catching an exception inside my case blocks, specifically an **invalid cast exception**. Anyone know why? Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it's not being caught?

Comment: That begs the question why is it compiling unless Option Strict is off.  What/how is `Fields` declared/defined?

Comment: Because my program crashes and tells me "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in program.exe. Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'A' to type 'B'"

Comment: @Plutonix it's an array of strings. Updated my post to show how I declared fields

Comment: Where is located this code? I mean, in which event? And is your app a 64bit application?

Comment: a) comparing an element from a string array to a string literal wont result in that exception b) that error message doesnt indicate strings being used c) *first chance* exceptions dont crash the app d) yes, where is the code located  I think you misdiagnosed where/what is causing it.  More likely an index out of range exception since you dont check the count/size after the Split.

Comment: It's inside a thread that reads data from Ethernet. I currently have my app set to CPU target of x86

Comment: Show this: thread that reads data from Ethernet.

Comment: Yea I edited my post to show the line my code is crashing

Comment: Well, if you declare `some_object` as Type A (`as A`), you cant assign an object of type B to it.  Unless there is some inheritance involved

Comment: You don't happen to have "Break when thrown" turned on in the exceptions dialog, do you?  If so, Visual Studio will break on the line that throws the exception, even if you handle it. https://i-msdn.sec.s-msft.com/dynimg/IC808490.jpeg.  It will look like your try / catch is being ignored.

Comment: Turns out that my exception setting was set to break when this type of exceptions occur. Thank you @BradleyUffner

Comment: I'll write up a quick answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you have "break when thrown" turned on for either this exception type, or all exceptions.

[image]

When this option is turned on, the dubugger will break on the line that throws the exception, even when it is inside a try / catch block, making it look like the block was ignored.  If you press continue, the `catch` block should run as normal though.

More than once, I've turned this option on to debug something specific and forgotten to turn it off.